# numpy version dependent result for 2d indexing on 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

I index a 1d array with 2d syntax.

With numpy 1.8.0 I get the following:

```
np.array([1,2,3])[:,[0,1]]
IndexError: too many indices
```

numpy 1.6.2 gives the result:

```
np.array([1,2,3])[:,[0,1]]
array([1, 2])
```

Does 1.8.0 behave "better"? Where is the change in behaviour documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy had a few bugs related to indexing arrays, most likely the behaviour in 1.6.2 is actually broken in some cases causing it to be disabled.

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how/why it works in 1.6.2 cause you are basically telling numpy that you want to index the 2nd dimension with the `,`.

I would recommend this instead:

```
numpy.array([1,2,3])[[0,1]]
```

Or even:

```
numpy.array([1,2,3]).take([0, 1])
```